# How can I differentiate the caller of the Prism's events?

Tags: wpf, events, prism, eventaggregator

I am using Prism's Event Aggregator and I publish an event from my composite control. But if a developer uses two instances of the control on the same form, how can a subscriber differentiate the events? What is the best practice?

Thank you.

Comment: what kind of event is it, what data does it contain? Normally the subscriber shouldn't have to care about the source, that's the whole point of using Event Aggregator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I just pass the caller or a callerId in the `EventMessage`, and the subscriber ignores the message if the caller isn't what it expects

```
// Subscribe
eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Subscribe(SomeMethod);
public void ShowNews(SomeEventMessage e)
{
    if (e.CallerId != this.Id)
        return;

    Do Work();
}

// Broadcast
eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Publish(
    new SomeEventMessage { CallerId = this.Id });
```